# Determining bijectivity of a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I was given a function from $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R \\f(x) = x^5 - 3\\$

I know this function is bijective because it is one to one, and onto. Then the question changes to $f: \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z \\f(x) = x^5 - 3\\$ and $f: \Bbb Q \rightarrow \Bbb Q \\f(x) = x^5 - 3\\$

I think this is also bijective but how would I calculate to make sure it is? Could I assume that if a function maps from the same domain to range and the function is not $f(x) = x^2$ or  $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$ or $f(x) = 2x$ that it is bijective?

Comment: Hint: can you find a rational number $x$ with $f(x) = 0$? If not, then how can $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be onto? (Likewise with $\mathbb{Z}$ in place of $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)No.You may not assume that.For example $f(x)=x^2(x-k)$ with $k \ne 0$.... (2) For $f(x)=x^5-3$, no integer $z$ satisfies $f(z)=0$.No rational $q$ satisfies $f(q)=0$ either,because $3^{1/5}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $3$ is not a fifth power of something rational. The function achieves no zero on $\mathbb{Q}$ and so is not surjective!

Comment: are you talking about the -3? What exactly do you mean 3 is not a fifth power

Comment: If x is rational then x^5 is not 3